# DATAGRID con filas vacias

Tags: c#, datagrid

lo que quiero hacer en C# es al llamar un datagrid, que me muestre una serie de filas (la cantidad la defino en cada caso) vacias para que quede mas presentable el formulario y luego voy trabajando en cada una de las celdas

muchas gracias

Pablo

Comment: Qué estás utilizando, windows forms... asp... wfc?? Estás usando Datagridview??

Comment: hola Hugo, uso windows forms y se me ocurre usar datagridview pero puedo usar cualquier otra alternativa, en c#

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una nueva fila en un DataGridView, está el método Add() en Rows.
Algo así:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

Luego para acceder y agregarle valores, obtienes su índice como Rows.Count-1

```
var i = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].value = "Escribe tu valor"
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: excelente muchas gracias

Comment: Si te sivió la respuesta puedes votar por ella... no sé por qué recibí un -15 por esta respuesta